# String in php resets to 0 if string is changed?

Tags: php

```
<?php
    $hello = "ok";
    $hello+= "hello again";
    echo $hello;
    ?>
```

Hello. I'd like to understand why this code prints 0 at the end?
Using the same method in javascript was working! Also, how do I make it that it change? I'd like the output to change according to any condition I make. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string concatenation operator in PHP is `.`, not `+`. When you write

```
$hello += "hello again";
```

PHP attempts to convert `$hello` and `"hello again"` into numbers, both of which become 0, so at the end of your code the value of `$hello` is 0. Try this instead:

```
$hello = "ok";
$hello .= "hello again";
echo $hello;
```

Output

```
okhello again
```

Answer (score 1):

Use .= instead of += in PHP:

```
<?php
    $hello = 'ok';
    $hello .= ' hello again';
    echo $hello;
?>
```